# Auto order by column (non-primary key)

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to alter a table so that any generic query will return data ordered by a column that is not indexed or a primary key? I would like

```
SELECT * from <table>
```

to have the same ordering as

```
SELECT * from <table> ORDER BY <misc_col>
```

without harming the integrity of the table or any of the current keys.

Comment: SQL tables and result sets represent *unordered* sets.  Add an `ORDER BY` if you want results in a proper order.  That is the only safe way to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the emphasis on the basics. I think the problem can only be solved by redefining my table structure (or creating a view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to use a `view`:

```
create view v_table as
    select t.*
    from t
    order by col;
```

Many databases either ignore such an `order by` or don't allow the syntax.  However, MySQL allows the syntax and selecting from the view should return the results in the order that you want.

Note:  An index on `t(col)` should improve performance.

Comment: Should it be noted any call to the view that imposes it's own order by will override the views order by.